# How to use one class (for database) with another class when database is not initialized in another class with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a class named Database, i want to use this class with another class to check information in the DB if it exists and execute certain queries to SQL. It looks something like this:

```
class Database:
    """Class to connect with the desired DB"""

    def __init__(self, host, database, user, password):
        self.con = psycopg2.connect(
            host=host,
            database=database,
            user=user,
            password=password
        )


    def select(self, query):
        cur = self.con.cursor()
        cur.execute(query)
        fetched_selects = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        self.con.close()
        return fetched_selects
```

So i want to do something like this:

```
def check_hostname(self):
    if socket.gethostname() in Database.select(??):
       ....
```

It has to be object oriented so that is why i am trying it in another class.

I made another class named Host:

```
class Host:

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = Database
        self.hostname = socket.gethostname()  # The Hostname of the system
        self.cores = psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)  # Total CPU Core count of Host
        self.total_RAM = f'{psutil.virtual_memory()[0] / 1024 ** 3:.2f}'  # Total Ram of System
        self.uptime = int(time.time() - psutil.boot_time())  # Uptime in Seconds
        self.free_ram = f'{psutil.virtual_memory()[4] / 1024 ** 3:.2f}'  # Available RAM in MB
        self.disk_usage = psutil.disk_usage('/')  # Used Disk Space in Percentage
```

I tried the 'check_hostname' function in here but since the Database class doesn't get initiated in the Host class it doesn't work.

Comment: 1) You need to properly instantiate `Database`: `self.db = Database(host, database, user, password)`.  2) You then need to use `self.db` in the `check_hostname(self)`  method: `if socket.gethostname() in self.db.select(??)` where `??` is replaced with actual query.

Comment: That is the problem. If i predefine a database it is not object oriented anymore.

Comment: Yes it is object oriented. This is not magic at some point you have to  define the database you are connecting to. `self.db = Database` is not going to achieve anything especially in relation to `Database.select()`. The class needs the connection info to do any work.

Comment: Would it not be an issue later if another database is used instead of the predefined db in "self.db = Database(host, database, user, password)"?

Comment: Then you instantiate another `Host` with different database credentials. A  `class` is basically an instance generator where each instance can be 'customized' . I would suggest looking up some basic Python tutorials that deal with `class`.